# defined proxy setting in mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, proxy

I am under a commercial proxy in my organization. I want to run mongo shell and connect to some external db on the net.
When I am working outside the proxy everything is fine..
inside the proxy I get:

```
connecting to: ds023475.mlab.com:23475/small-talkz
2016-07-20T10:37:46.913+0300 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 54.159.13.56:23475 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
2016-07-20T10:37:46.913+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to sever ds023475.mlab.com:23475, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:231:14
```

how can I define the proxy in my mongo shell?